# How to fix error: [Dagger/MissingBinding]

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to inject a repository into a ViewModel constructor as a dependency using Hilt but I keep getting the same error:

error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.comfyluxxy.repositories.MainHouseRepository cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.

The repository is declared in my AppModule and is annotated with @Provides as shown below

AppModule.kt

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideHouseRepository() = MainHouseRepository() as HouseRepository

}
```

And here's the ViewModel that uses the repository.

HouseViewModel.kt

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class HouseViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val houseRepository: MainHouseRepository
) : ViewModel() {

  // my code here

}
```

I also tried doing this but it still resulted into the same error

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object ViewModelModule {
  
  @Provides
  @ViewModelScoped
  fun provideHouseRepository() = MainHouseRepository() as HouseRepository

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you're providing `HouseRepository` (abstraction) and it expecting `MainHouseRepository` (implementation) to be provided. You should be expecting `HouseRepository`. I made this and some other changes in your code:

Assuming:

```kotlin
interface HouseRepository

class MainHouseRepository : HouseRepository
```

Provide:

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object ViewModelModule {
    // Do not cast the type, use polymorphism instead.
    @Provides
    fun provideHouseRepository(): HouseRepository = MainHouseRepository()
}
```

Inject:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class HouseViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val houseRepository: HouseRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    // my code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. The build was successful. I'm going to do some more testing just to make sure. But so far so good.